# File Writing Issues

Tags: python, file, tkinter

Recently I was working on a project which uses the function `asksaveasfile()`. After using this and changing the `/`'s to `\`'s, I kept getting an error essentially telling me that when using `replace('/', '\\')` (Because \ Is An Escape Char You Need 2), The program was using `\\` instead of `\`.

Here is an example I created in which I get the same error:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

files = [('Python Files', '*.py')]
get_file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension = files)
get_file = str(get_file).replace('/', '\\')
file = open(str(get_file), "w")

mainloop()
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aries/Documents/saveas.py", line 30, in <module>
    file = open(str(get_file), "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.TextIOWrapper 
name='C:\\Users\\MY_NAME\\Documents\\MY_PROJECT\\test23.py' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: On Windows, Python will deal with `/` delimiters in paths automatically, so you don't even need this code.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to change backslashes to forward slashes. Windows has supported backslashes for a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is not related to backslashes.  `asksaveasfile()` returns an open file handle, not the file name. If you want the file name, call `asksaveasfilename()` - but why?

Comment: I did +1 origionally, but since he answered within 10 minutes, I had to wait before accepting. Please pay more attention before commenting like that.

Comment: @AriesNinja with `askopenfile(..)` i believe you can get rid of `open(...)` too, it opens the file that you select with `filedialog`

Comment: Kind of, but for me it opens the file in append mode.